# Does it possible to partial keyspaces to another DC?

Tags: cassandra

I have 4 keyspaces and 1 "DC1," with 3 keyspaces using `SimpleStrategy` and 1 of them using NetworkTopologyStrategy`. I want to add a new "DC2" data center.  Replication will be set as DC1:3 and DC2:3.

Will it possible to replicate only one keyspace to the new DC? This means that 3 keyspaces only replicate to DC1 and 1 keyspace replicates to BOTH DC1 and DC2.

Please confirm, is it possible for partial replication between DCs or not?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can replicate keyspace between only required DCs - there is no requirement for replicating to all data centers, except some system keyspaces.

But be careful - before adding the new DC, **change all existing keyspaces to use network topology strategy** - if you continue to use simple strategy, data from that keyspaces will go to new DC as well.  Refer to [DSE Admin guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsChangeKSStrategy.html) for details on how to do it

Comment: so it is mandatory to change 'NetworkTopologyStrategy' while adding new DC whether we require to replicate the data on other DC or not? else it will replicate to other DC with using Simple Strategy.

Comment: Yes, you shouldn’t use simple strategy with multiple data centers

Comment: But, how come SimpleStrategy Keyspace is aware of new DC information? how come data will go to new DC with SimpleStrategy Keyspace ?

I have only 2 data centers. DC1 and DC2.
and i have 4 keyspaces (KS1,KS2,KS3,KS4). and out 4 keyspaces.
KS1,KS2,KS4 using SimpleStrategy. and i want data to store DC1 only not DC2.
and another keyspace KS3 was using NetworkTopologyStrategy and data should replicate between DC1 and DC2. and i will not change SimpleStrategy to NetworkToplogyStrategy for KS1,KS2,KS4. 

Does this scenario will support or not ?

Comment: SimpleStrategy doesn't care about DCs - it just puts the replicas somewhere - in case of multiple DCs the data from keyspace could be in different DCs. So you **must** switch KS1,KS2 & KS4 to use NetworkTopologyStrategy with replication only in DC1, while KS3 will be replicated to both DCs